# Power of arithmetic mean

Tags: inequality

Does there exist a finite universal constant $m>1$ such that for every $0\leq a,\lambda\leq 1$ the following holds? $$[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]^m\leq \lambda^a(1-\lambda)^{1-a}$$

My guess is that perhaps there exists a small $m$ since $a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)\leq 1$ since as $m$ increases the power of the arithmetic mean decreases.

I have tried to apply Jensen's and Holder's inequality but nothing much can be said.

Comment: Hint: take log on both sides.  The RHS should remind you of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I know that taking log and applying Jensen's inequality helps to prove am-gm inequality, but the question here is raising the arithmetic mean by some power you can upper bound it with the geometric mean.

Comment: Since $\log$ is concave, Jensen's inequality should give you some equivalent conditions for the equality (without $m$) to hold.  Since the question asks whether $m$ exists, it suffices to construct it from the gap.

Answer (score 0):

*This answers the [original version of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2934584/1).*

## Graphical view

$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xlr}{5,5}{0x2194}$
$$\star \triangleq a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & — & \lambda & \xlr{1-a} & \star & \xlr{a} & 1-\lambda & — & \rlap{1 \to x\text{-axis}}\\
| & & | & & | & & \downarrow & \color{red}{\nearrow} \\
| & & | & & | & & \color{red}{\log(1-\lambda)} \\
| & & | & & \downarrow & \color{red}{\nearrow} \color{blue}{/} \\
| & & | & & \llap{\color{red}{\log\star}} & \color{blue}{/} \\
| & & | & \quad\color{red}{/} & \downarrow & \!\!\!\!\!\color{blue}{/} \\
| & & | & \color{red}{/} & \color{blue}{\bullet \; \rlap{\xleftarrow{\text{weight mean}} a\log\lambda+(1-a)\log(1-\lambda)}} \\
| & & \downarrow & \color{red}{/} \color{blue}{\nearrow} & \\
| & & \color{red}{\log\lambda} & & & \rlap{\text{Legend}} \\
\downarrow & \color{red}{\swarrow} & & & \rlap{\color{red}{\text{concave function }f(x) = \log(x)}} \\
\llap{\text{negative $y$-axis}} & & & & \rlap{\color{blue}{\text{straight line joining }} \color{red}{\log\lambda \text{ and } \log(1-\lambda)}}
\end{array}
From the above "graph" of the concave function $\log$, it's *observed* that
$$0 \ge \color{red}{\underbrace{\log[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]}_{\Large\log\star}} \ge \color{blue}{\underbrace{a\log\lambda+(1-a)\log(1-\lambda)}_{\Large \bullet \text{ weighted mean}}}, \tag1 \label1$$
which is an application Jensen's inequality on the concave function $\log$.

## Take $\log$ on the original problem

\begin{align}
[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]^m &\le \lambda^a(1-\lambda)^{1-a} \\
\iff m\, \color{red}{\underbrace{\log[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]}_{\Large\log\star}} &\le \color{blue}{\underbrace{a\log\lambda+(1-a)\log(1-\lambda)}_{\Large \bullet \text{ weighted mean}}} \le 0 \tag2
\end{align}
To answer the question, just take any $m \ne 1$ so that $$m \ge \frac{a\log\lambda+(1-a)\log(1-\lambda)}{\log[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]} \stackrel{\eqref{1}}{\ge} 1 \tag3$$
*as long as $\color{red}{\log\star} = \log[a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)]$ is defined and nonzero*.

## Two extreme cases when the above argument fails

- $\star = 0$, so $\color{red}{\log\star}$ is *undefined*.  In this case, $a\lambda = (1-a)(1-\lambda)=0$  Either $(a,\lambda)=(1,0)$ or $(a,\lambda)=(0,1)$, so $\lambda(1-\lambda)=0$, and the desired inequality holds for *any* $m > 0$.
- $\star = 1$, so $\color{red}{\log\star} = 0$

  \begin{align}
  1 &= a+(1-a) \tag4 \\
  &= a\lambda + (1-a)(1-\lambda) \tag5 \\
  (4)-(5): 0 &= a(1-\lambda)+(1-a)\lambda \\
  \therefore \begin{cases} a=0\\\lambda=0 \end{cases} &\text{ or } \begin{cases} a=1\\\lambda=1 \end{cases}
  \end{align}

  In this case, the LHS of the desired inequality equals one for *any* $m \in \Bbb R$, while the RHS, containing $0^0$, becomes *undefined*.

Comment: Your answer looks very nice, but honestly, I don't understand anything from it.

Comment: @Surb OP's question is "given $a,\lambda \in [0,1]$, does there exist $m>1$ such that ..., so I've given a lower bound for $m$.  Taking $\log$ on both sides basically *won't* change the problem, unless any side is not positive.  That's the case that I'm elaborating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure what you mean either. I think my question is whether there exists a global constant $m$ such that the above inequality holds for all $a,\lambda\in[0,1]$. Of course as you said taking log won't change the problem, and plugging any $(a,\lambda)$ into your eq 3 could be a lower bound of $m$, but it is unclear whether a lower bound is finite and/or does not depend on $(a,\lambda)$. The problem asks whether there exists a finite $m$ but I would love to know a concrete lower bound.

Comment: @user50394 The _order_ of variables is very important.  In the question body, you've put "a" and "λ" _in front of_ "m".  This is interpreted as finding the truth value of "$\forall a,λ \exists m: ...$", so it's legitimate to construct "m" from "a" and "λ".

Comment: I thought it did not make too much sense to find $m$ that depends on $a,\lambda$ since clearly $a\lambda+(1-a)(1-\lambda)\leq 1$. In case the expression may cause any confusion I'll update the post.

Comment: @user50394 [A question should not be a moving target](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).  Please consider arranging your quantifiers and variables in the right order to avoid confusion next time.